# How do I discover which process is making my hard drive go crazy? (need disk io equivalent of task manager's cpu % column)

Tags: windows, monitoring, filesystems, hard-drive

When I notice my system getting sluggish, the first thing I do is open up Task Manager to see if some process or another is using up 100% of the cpu.  What do I do when I hear my hard drive churning away like crazy, but the cpu is 99% idle?  How do I sort my processes by "disk io in last 5 secods" or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filemon or procmon from the [sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx); process explorer also helps. Free download, unzip and run them as admin user...

Answer (score 3):

If you start task manager and go to the process tab, you can then add columns from the View menu. IO Writes and Reads might show you right away.  If not I would go with the sysinternals stuff Bart mentioned.

Comment: I found delta I/O Delta Read and I/O Delta Write to be the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You might compare snapshots using wmic:

> wmic.exe process list  io /every:10
>   /repeat:6

This command will take a snapshot of your process IO 6 times at 10 second intervals.

This command:

```
wmic process list  statistics /format:list
```

will give you non-process specific IO as well, like paging file statistics.

Rob